# Trying to reduce #rows and columns in matrix by calculating averages of x by y cells in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

First time posting here.  I have a bit of knowledge of coding in VBA, but obviously not enough.  I have created an excel spreadsheet that automatically imports measurement data from a text file and converts the data into a matrix, so I can use it for a 3D surface plot.  Unfortunately, sometimes this matrix has more than 255 rows/columns which exceed the maximum for 3d surface plots.

So what I am trying to do is create a Sub that reduces the number of cells for the 3d surface plot by taking averages of x by y cells and writing them into a different 'matrix' on another sheet.

So I am trying to create a Sub with 4 inputs: name of the source sheet, name of the destination sheet, x-ratio, and y-ratio.  x-ratio being the number of cells horizontal to combine and y-ratio being the number of cells vertical to combine.  So if x-ratio = 3 and y-ratio = 2, the Sub should take cells A1:B3 from the source sheet, calculate the average and write it into cell A1 of the destination sheet, A4:B6 to A2.  Similarly, C1:D3 needs to go to B1 and so on.... The number of rows and columns in the source sheet is different every time.

There's also a catch if I have for instance defined x-ratio as 3, but at the end of the row there are only 2 columns left, then it should only calculate the average of the last 2 columns.  The same is true if there are not enough rows left.

Here's the code that I have written:

```
Public Sub ChngGraphRes(Sourcegraph As String, Destgraph As String, ratio As Long, yRatio As Long)

    Dim SrcRng As Range
    Dim CurPos As Range
    Dim SrcAvg As Double
    Dim DestRng As Range
    Dim sRw As Long
    Dim dRw As Long
    Dim Cl As Long
    
    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Destgraph)
    Sht.Cells.Clear
    
    Dim lstRow As Long
    Dim lstCol As Long
    lstRow = Worksheets(Sourcegraph).Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row - 1
    lstCol = Worksheets(Sourcegraph).Range("a1").End(xlToRight).Column - 1
    
    Set CurPos = Range("'" & Sourcegraph & "'!A1")
    Set DestRng = Range("'" & Destgraph & "'!A1")
    Do While CurPos.Row < lstRow - yRatio
        Do While CurPos.Column < lstCol - xRatio
            SrcRng = Range(CurPos).Resize(yRatio, xRatio)
            SrcAvg = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(SrcRng))
            DestRng.Value = SrcAvg
            CurPos = CurPos.Offset(0, xRatio)
            DestRng = DestRng.Offset(0, 1)
        Loop
        SrcRng = Range(CurPos).Resize(yRatio, lstCol - CurPos.Column)
        SrcAvg = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(SrcRng))
        DestRng.Value = SrcAvg
        sRw = CurPos.Row
        dRw = DestRng.Row
        CurPos = Range(Sourcegraph & "!A1")
        CurPos = CurPos.Offset(sRw + yRatio, 0)
        DestRng = Range(Destgraph & "!A1")
        DestRng = DestRng.offest(dRw + 1, 0)
    Loop
    Do While CurPos.Column < lstCol - xRatio
        SrcRng = Range(CurPos).Resize(lstRow - CurPos.Row, xRatio)
        SrcAvg = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(SrcRng))
        DestRng.Value = SrcAvg
        CurPos = CurPos.Offset(0, xRatio)
        DestRng = DestRng.Offset(0, 1)
    Loop
    SrcRng = Range(CurPos).Resize(lstRow - CurPos.Row, lstCol - CurPos.Column)
    SrcAvg = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(SrcRng))
    DestRng.Value = SrcAvg            
            
End Sub
```

I am probably going about this completely the wrong way because I am getting errors left and right and I have no idea how to fix them.

Comment: Start the easy way.  Create a function that takes a range ( of a single cell), an x ratio value and a y ratio value and then checks the  xratio /yratio offsets are not empty before calculating the average which is returned by the function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, freeflow

New day, fresh ideas.  I took your advice and took small steps.  I restarted writing the code from scratch, and instead of using the whole method with ranges I worked with cells(row, column) this time.  Much easier, and less prone to errors.

Here's the working code:

```
Public Sub ChngGraphRes(srcGraph As String, destGraph As String, xRatio As Long, yRatio As Long)
          
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet
    Dim destSht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRw As Long
    Dim lastCl As Long
    Dim curSrcRw As Long
    Dim curSrcCl As Long
    Dim curDestRw As Long
    Dim curDestCl As Long
    
    'Set source and destination sheets
    Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(srcGraph)
    Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(destGraph)
    
    'Clear destination sheet
    destSht.Cells.Clear
        
    'Check how many rows and columns in source sheet
    lastRw = srcSht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    lastCl = srcSht.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    
    'Set start position
    curSrcRw = 2
    curSrcCl = 2
    curDestRw = 1
    curDestCl = 1
    
    'Calculate averages
    With srcSht
        Do While curSrcRw < lastRw - yRatio
            Do While curSrcCl < lastCl - xRatio
                destSht.Cells(curDestRw, curDestCl) = WorksheetFunction.Average(.Cells(curSrcRw, curSrcCl).Resize(yRatio, xRatio))
                curSrcCl = curSrcCl + xRatio
                curDestCl = curDestCl + 1
            Loop
            destSht.Cells(curDestRw, curDestCl) = WorksheetFunction.Average(.Cells(curSrcRw, curSrcCl).Resize(yRatio, lastCl - curSrcCl + 1))
            curSrcRw = curSrcRw + yRatio
            curSrcCl = 2
            curDestRw = curDestRw + 1
            curDestCl = 1
        Loop
        Do While curSrcCl < lastCl - xRatio
                destSht.Cells(curDestRw, curDestCl) = WorksheetFunction.Average(.Cells(curSrcRw, curSrcCl).Resize(lastRw - curSrcRw + 1, xRatio))
                curSrcCl = curSrcCl + xRatio
                curDestCl = curDestCl + 1
        Loop
        destSht.Cells(curDestRw, curDestCl) = WorksheetFunction.Average(.Cells(curSrcRw, curSrcCl).Resize(lastRw - curSrcRw + 1, lastCl - curSrcCl + 1))
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).